# Single mandatory question with multiple "I accept condition X" (checkboxes?) in a Google Docs Form?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms

I have a form with several fields (name, a URL, etc.) that's part of an approval request process. I'd like to have a question with several checkboxes which all must be checked before a form can be submitted. This is similar to "I accept condition X" before one requests approval, but with multiple conditions.

If I use only one mandatory question with several checkboxes, it's sufficient to check one of the boxes to allow the form to be submitted. I want a kind of "AND" condition for all checkboxes.

So far, I can only see a way to do this by making separate mandatory questions with single checkboxes for each condition. This is a little ugly,  because it takes up vertical space, as each question has space for a title, etc.

Just wondering if anyone knows of a better way.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't just have all of the conditions listed, and have them check a single box? My school's wireless authentication page has 2 checkboxes, and I'd say at least 9/10 people only check the first one, then ask "why'd the page show up again?"

Comment: Precisely! When it's refused because they don't accept all conditions, I want them to read them all. If it's all in one box, they'll just read the first part, click and submit. Google forms highlight the mandatory unanswered parts after a submission attempt.

Comment: While that's a noble intention, I assure you that the reality will be much more along the lines of "shoot, I missed a couple boxes? _check, check, check_, OK! on my way now..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this and saving white space is to use a "Grid" option.

When making/editing your question, choose the "grid" type of question. This will allow you to create a multi-row question in which all rows must be filled out if the question is required.

In the screenshot you can see that each row would be a single condition of the terms, and there can be only 1 column with the label "I accept" or whatever you like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The grid option is a great idea but I also discovered that selecting the 'response validation' option allows you to require a certain number of options to be selected before a form can be submitted. Simply request that the number of tick boxes you've added are the required number and you can keep the nice format of the tick box option!